# Liferay Jax-RS : Unable to call simple REST apis, getting 403 and 405

Tags: rest, jax-rs, liferay, liferay-7

I am using Liferay 7.3.

Trying to build Rest APIs using JAX-RS and I have generated token by following official documentation here https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018166411-JAX-RS#using-oauth-20-to-invoke-a-jax-rs-web-service

getting 403 [Forbidden] for @GET and 405 [method not allowed] for @POST

```
package com.liferay.jaxrstest.application;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.jaxrs.whiteboard.JaxrsWhiteboardConstants;

@Component(
    property = {
        JaxrsWhiteboardConstants.JAX_RS_APPLICATION_BASE + "=/greetings",
        JaxrsWhiteboardConstants.JAX_RS_NAME + "=Greetings.Rest"
    },
    service = Application.class
)
public class LiferaxJaxRsTestApplication extends Application {

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return Collections.<Object>singleton(this);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String working() {
        return "It works!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/morning")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Good morning!";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/morning")
    // @Produces("text/plain")
    // @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello(User user) {
        return "Good morning!" + user.getFirstName();
    }
}

class User {

    private String firstName;
    
    public User(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to test one of your created endpoints you should use the path created to it.

To test the good morning GET endpoint you should do a GET request to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/o/greetings/morning
```

…with no Body. As you are using OAuth2, you have to pass the token using the Authorization tab in Postman. There, you can configure how to get a new token and to use it.

[image: Image of how you should configure it]

I am also considering that in your OAuth2 configuration in the Control Panel of the Portal you checked the box for `GET` and `POST` for the `Greetings.Rest` service in the Scopes tab.

Finally, to get the `clientId` and the `clientSecret`, go to

> Control Panel → Configuration → OAuth2 Administration.